# This subcollection of the base is also a base

Tags: general-topology

Let $B_n$ be a countable base of a locally compact Hausdorff space $X$. I am trying to show that $S = \{B_n \mid \overline{B_n} \text{ is compact} \}$ is also a base.

I imagine the proof to be short and simple but I can't seem to find it.

The goal: Given an open set $U$ in $X$ I want to show that there are $B_n \in S$ such that $U = \bigcup_n B_n$. I'm not sure how to use that $X$ is Hausdorff.

My thoughts on this: I know that a compact subset of a Hausdorff space is closed but since $\overline{B_n} $ is already closed this doesn't come in handy. Similarly, if $u$ is any point in $U$ the local compactness gives a compact neighbourhood $N$ of $u$. But I don't see how to relate $N$ to the elements in $S$.

Hence my question: How to prove this?

Comment: What does locally compact mean ?

Comment: @WLOG I explain it in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important point is that in a locally compact Hausdorff space, every point has a neighbourhood basis consisting of compact neighbourhoods.

Given that, it is clear that for every $x\in U$ there is a compact neighbourhood $x \in \overset{\Large\circ}{K} \subset K \subset U$, and since $\{B_n\}$ is a basis, there is an $n_x$ with $x \in B_{n_x} \subset K$. Then $\overline{B_{n_x}}$ is clearly compact, hence $B_{n_x}\in S$, and the criterion for $S$ to be a basis is verified.

So let's see that the compact neighbourhoods of a point $x$ form a neighbourhood basis. Let $K$ a compact neighbourhood of $x$, and $U$ any open neighbourhood of $x$. We want to see that $U$ contains a compact neighbourhood $L$ of $x$. Let $V = U\cap \overset{\Large\circ}{K}$. Then $V$ is an open neighbourhood of $x$ contained in $U$, and $K\setminus V$ is a compact set disjoint from $x$. By the Hausdorff property, we find disjoint open sets $W$ and $Z$ such that $x \in W \subset V$ and $K\setminus V \subset Z$. Then $L := \overline{W} \subset \overline{V} \subset K$, so $L$ is a compact neighbourhood of $x$, and $L \cap Z = \varnothing$, so in particular $L\cap (K\setminus V) = \varnothing$, which means $L \subset V\cup (X\setminus K)$, but since $L\subset K$, we have $L \subset V \subset U$, as desired.

Comment: But if $A$ is any set contained in a compact set $K$ it is not true that its closure is also in $K$. This is only true if we replace compact with closed, no?

Comment: I am asking this because I assume where you write "Then $\overline{B_{n_x}}$ is clearly compact" you are using that closed subsets of compact sets are compact.

Comment: We're in a Hausdorff space. In a Hausdorff space, every compact set is closed.

Comment: Oh, thank you, I knew that but I didn't think of it. I have one more question: Why is $K \setminus V$ compact? I understand that $K \setminus V$ is compact in $K$ with the subspace topology but does it follow that it is also compact in the surrounding space?

Comment: Being compact is an intrinsic property of a space, that doesn't depend on the surrounding space. Since $V$ is open, $K\setminus V$ is a closed subset of $K$. And, as you know (you wrote it in your comment above), closed subsets of compact sets are compact.

Comment: I just figured it out this very second. Thank you for your help!

Comment: But Hausdorff only gives separation of points. You are using it to separate a point and a set. But I suspect the argument is correct and there is just one step in between that I have to work out.

Comment: It's important that the set which we separate from the point is compact. You can separate each $y \in K\setminus V$ from $x$ by open sets $W_y$ and $Z_y$ by the Hausdorff property. Can you see how it continues?

Comment: Oh, probably using a finite subcover. I need to some time to think and work this out in full, thank you for your help!

Comment: Ok, I get it. Thank you for your help. For my learning I will reproduce my understanding here in the comments:

Comment: Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space. We claim that every point $x \in X$ has a compact neighbourhood base. We show this by showing that the set of all compact neighbourhoods of $x$ is in fact a neighbourhood base. So let $U$ be any open neighbourhood of $x$. Then the goal is to produce a compact neighbourhood $C$ of $x$ contained in $U$.

Comment: Since $X$ is locally compact there exists a compact neighbourhood $K$ of $x$. We let $V = \mathring{K}\cap V$ and note that $V$ is open. Hence $K \setminus V$ is a closed subset of $K$ and since $X$ is Hausdorff it follows that $K \setminus V$ is compact. We will use this in the following construction.

Comment: Let $y$ be any point in $K \setminus V$. Then since $X$ is Hausdorff there exist open disjoint sets $U_y$ and $V_y$ such that $x \in U_y \subseteq V$ and $y \in V_y$. The collection $V_y$ is an open cover of $K \setminus V$ and therefore has a finite subcover $V_{y_1},\dots V_{y_n}$. Note that $\bigcap_k U_{y_k}$ and $\bigcup_k V_{y_k}$ are disjoint open sets and hence $\overline{\bigcap_k U_{y_k}}\subseteq \left ( \bigcup_k V_{y_k}\right )^c$.

Comment: Let $C = \overline{\bigcap_k U_{y_k}}$. We claim that $C$ is compact and $C \cap U^c = \varnothing$. Since $C$ is a closed subset of $K$ it is clear that it is compact. On the other hand note that
$$ C \cap U^c = C \cap K \cap U^c \subseteq C \cap \bigcup_k V_{y_k} = \varnothing$$